# Signal R Persistant Connection memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, signalr

I have a product that uses SignalR (the .NET Framework Version) for its communications. In order for it to work everywhere, we offer that customers can talk to the client via a normal Server>Cloud>Client connection or directly via a SelfHosted SignalR connection.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that it seems that the SelfHosted Connection seems to have a memory leak when sending data directly to the client

**The cloud Connection version is this**

```
var _connection = new Connection(ServerUrl);
_connection.Received += OnReceived;
IClientTransport connectionType;
var connectionType = new WebSocketTransport();
_connection.Start(connectionType)
```

With send from this like this:

```
private void HandleResult(HeaderPacket headerPacket)
{
   _connection.Send(headerPacket); //Send data to Client via Cloud
}
```

(above code have no memory leaks)

---

The SelfHosted Version is this

```
var url = "http://*:8889";
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
{}

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.Configuration.MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            app.MapSignalR();
            app.MapSignalR<ServerEndPoint>("/Server");
        }
    }


    public class ServerEndPoint : PersistentConnection
    {
        private void HandleResult(HeaderPacket response)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            Connection.Send(response.ClientConnectionId, data);
        }

        protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
        { ... }
    }
```

It is the
Connection.Send(response.ClientConnectionId, data);
Call that makes the memory increase with every call, also with only a single connection.. It should out a few MB and quickly (after 100 calls) it is using 50MB.

If I comment out the send part as the only thing there is no memory leak (indicating it is not the rest of the code that has the memory leak).

I've tried to upgrade latest NuGet packages but the leak persists so I assume it must be some odd setting I'm missing :-(

Comment: How large in KB is `data`?

Comment: It varies greatly from call to call but big calls are 200-300 KB of data, other only a few KB

Comment: Some of them could be in the LOH, which doesn't compact very often (which _looks_ like a memory leak, but isn't). And 50MB isn't much, so the GC is well within its rights to do that. Have you tried setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=net-5.0 every few minutes? Does that help?

Comment: That is just in testing.. If we let the program run in days it increase to over 1GB of extra memory used (sorry for not mentioning that)... We already have a GC.Collect() schedule for every 30 sec but it does not "catch/clean" the memory build-up :-(.

Comment: Did you set the _explicit_ property I said? `GC.Collect` will _not_ compact the LOH otherwise.

Comment: Yes. It did not help (Which also make sense since it is only 1 of the 2 signalR connection method (with same data) have the memory leak)